# Printing statements using a method

Tags: java, string, methods, println

Basically I've been set some work where I have to have 4 methods but I don't really understand how methods work. One of these methods basically has to print out two set statements that's it and I have no idea how to do it as most examples across the web deal with methods being used for maths and nothing as simple as printing out two lines for a title. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please read a basic Java tutorial.

Comment: show a little work, code, effort.

Comment: What exactly do you want your software to do? Show us output(s) and input(s), and a little code wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I can't believe that "examples across the web" doesn't deal with printing !!

Answer (score 2):

Method is just a way of extracting a piece of code and making it callable on demand.  So if you print out two lines...

```
 System.out.println("This is line 1");
 System.out.println("This is line 2");
```

And you want to call it more than once, then you would extract it into a method.

```
 private void myNewMethod()
 { 
  System.out.println("This is line 1");
  System.out.println("This is line 2");
 }
```

Then call that method from anywhere in your program like so

```
 myNewMethod();
```

These types of questions are off topic however as you need to demonstrate an understanding of your problem before we can help fix it.